# variable gets forgotten after print statement

Tags: sml, smlnj

Why does this compile?

```
fun foo (h::t) =
    h = hd(t);
```

But this does not

```
fun foo (h::t) =
    PolyML.print (h::t);
    print "\n";
    h = hd(t);
```

?

```
Value or constructor (h) has not been declared   Found near =( h, hd(t))

Value or constructor (t) has not been declared   Found near =( h, hd(t))
Exception- Fail "Static errors (pass2)" raised
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your frustration with the language prevents you from solving your problem(s) more than the limitations of the language. As I said in a previous answer, semicolons cannot be used like you used them. You need to wrap those statements inside parentheses:

```
fun foo (h::t) =
  (
    PolyML.print (h::t);
    print "\n";
    h = hd(t)
  )
```

Furthermore, you first snippet doesn't need a semicolon:

```
fun foo (h::t) =
    h = hd(t)
```

Here's the thing, in SML semicolons are not used to terminate statements, they're used to separate expressions. Think of `;` as a binary operator, just like `+` or `-`. With the added constraint that you need parentheses around.

Also, you're probably using the `=` operator in the wrong way inside `h = hd(t)`. It's not assignment, it's an equality check, just like `==` in other languages. If you want assignment, you need a `ref` type.

It's probably better to ask what exactly you're trying to solve, because at this point you're totally misunderstanding the syntax and semantics of SML and we can't really write a tutorial on in here.